# Difference between Node object and Element object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am totally confused between [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) object and [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object.
`document.getElementById()` returns `Element` object while `document.getElementsByClassName()`
returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object (Collection of Elements or Nodes?)

If a div is an Element Object then what about div Node object?

What is a Node Object?

Are document object, Element object and Text Object are also Node object?

As per David Flanagan's book 'The Document object, Its Element Objects and text objects are all Node objects'.

So How come an object can inherit properties/methods of Element object as well as Node object?

If yes, I guess Node Class and Element Class are related in prototypal tree of inheritance.

```
 <div id="test">
           <p class="para"> 123 </p>
           <p class="para"> abc </p>
 </div>
 <p id="id_para"> next </p>

document.documentElement.toString();    // [object HTMLHtmlElement]

var div = document.getElementById("test");
div.toString();                         // [object HTMLDivElement]                       

var p1 = document.getElementById("id_para");
p1.toString();                          // [object HTMLParagraphElement]

var p2 = document.getElementsByClassName("para");
p2.toString();                          //[object HTMLCollection]
```

Comment: There are 12 types of nodes, element being one of them

Comment: aren't all these 12 types are Element Object also? like 1 = ELEMENT_NODE, 3 = TEXT_NODE, I think both are Element object also.

Comment: No they aren't. Element is only a single type of node.

Comment: Is this still in used nowadays? I ask since seeing Mozilla's docs it says:
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names);
elements is a live HTMLCollection of found elements.

So, apparently, getElementsByClassName does not return a NodeList anymore.

Comment: The WHATWG: `The nodes representing HTML elements in the DOM...` (3.2.2). Some nitpicker could draw from it there *is* kind of a difference here. Nevertheless, it seems the spec uses this terms (DOM nodes representing HTML elements and just HTML elements) in an interchangeable way.

Answer (score 685, accepted):

A `node` is the generic name for any type of object in the DOM hierarchy.  A `node` could be one of the built-in DOM elements such as `document` or `document.body`, it could be an HTML tag specified in the HTML such as `<input>` or `<p>` or it could be a text node that is created by the system to hold a block of text inside another element.  So, in a nutshell, a `node` is any DOM object.

An `element` is one specific type of `node` as there are many other types of nodes (text nodes, comment nodes, document nodes, etc...).

The DOM consists of a hierarchy of nodes where each node can have a parent, a list of child nodes and a nextSibling and previousSibling.  That structure forms a tree-like hierarchy.  The `document` node has the `html` node as its child.
The `html` node has its list of child nodes (the `head` node and the `body` node).  The `body` node would have its list of child nodes (the top level elements in your HTML page) and so on.

So, a `nodeList` is simply an array-like list of `nodes`.

An element is a specific type of node, one that can be directly specified in the HTML with an HTML tag and can have properties like an `id` or a `class`. can have children, etc...  There are other types of nodes such as comment nodes, text nodes, etc... with different characteristics.  Each node has a property `.nodeType` which reports what type of node it is.  You can see the various types of nodes here (diagram from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)):

[image]

You can see an `ELEMENT_NODE` is one particular type of node where the `nodeType` property has a value of `1`.

So `document.getElementById("test")` can only return one node and it's guaranteed to be an element (a specific type of node).  Because of that it just returns the element rather than a list.

Since `document.getElementsByClassName("para")` can return more than one object, the designers chose to return a `nodeList` because that's the data type they created for a list of more than one node.  Since these can only be elements (only elements typically have a class name), it's technically a `nodeList` that only has nodes of type element in it and the designers could have made a differently named collection that was an `elementList`, but they chose to use just one type of collection whether it had only elements in it or not.

---

**EDIT:**  HTML5 defines an `HTMLCollection` which is a list of HTML Elements (not any node, only Elements).  A number of properties or methods in HTML5 now return an `HTMLCollection`.  While it is very similar in interface to a `nodeList`, a distinction is now made in that it only contains Elements, not any type of node.

The distinction between a `nodeList` and an `HTMLCollection` has little impact on how you use one (as far as I can tell), but the designers of HTML5 have now made that distinction.

For example, the `element.children` property returns a live HTMLCollection.

Comment: So all elements are nodes, but not all nodes are elements... right? I was just pondering whether to describe things as nodes or elements in JavaScript functions when iterating through certain things.

Comment: I know I'm resurrecting a 7-year-old post, but I just wanted to say thank you for this excellent and thorough explanation! Made complete sense.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this wonderful answer. Very brief, yet very thorough. And answered the questions and confusion I alway had in my head as to why we call this thing nodeList rather than elementList. Thank you!

Comment: Very good answer. Just a small correction: "_The `document` node would have its list of child nodes (the `head` node and the `body` node)._" — The `head` and `body` nodes are not children of `document`. `document` has one child, which is `html` (`document.documentElement`). `document.documentElement` / `html` is the parent of `head` and `body`. :-)

Comment: @genbatro - Thx.  I've updated the answer to reflect that it goes document > [html] > [head, body] and so on...

Answer (score 102):

`Element` inherits from `Node`, in the same way that `Dog` inherits from `Animal`.

An `Element` object "is-a" `Node` object, in the same way that a `Dog` object "is-a" `Animal` object.

`Node` is for implementing a tree structure, so its methods are for `firstChild`, `lastChild`, `childNodes`, etc.  It is more of a class for a generic tree structure.

And then, some `Node` objects are also `Element` objects.  `Element` inherits from `Node`.  `Element` objects actually represents the objects as specified in the HTML file by the tags such as `<div id="content"></div>`.  The `Element` class define properties and methods such as `attributes`, `id`, `innerHTML`, `clientWidth`, `blur()`, and `focus()`.

Some `Node` objects are text nodes and they are not `Element` objects.  Each `Node` object has a `nodeType` property that indicates what type of node it is, for HTML documents:

```
1: Element node
3: Text node
8: Comment node
9: the top level node, which is document
```

We can see some examples in the console:

```
> document instanceof Node
  true

> document instanceof Element
  false

> document.firstChild
  <html>...</html>

> document.firstChild instanceof Node
  true

> document.firstChild instanceof Element
  true

> document.firstChild.firstChild.nextElementSibling
  <body>...</body>

> document.firstChild.firstChild.nextElementSibling === document.body
  true

> document.firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling
  #text

> document.firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling instanceof Node
  true

> document.firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling instanceof Element
  false

> Element.prototype.__proto__ === Node.prototype
  true
```

The last line above shows that `Element` inherits from `Node`. (that line won't work in IE due to `__proto__`.  Will need to use Chrome, Firefox, or Safari).

By the way, the `document` object is the top of the node tree, and `document` is a `Document` object, and `Document` inherits from `Node` as well:

```
> Document.prototype.__proto__ === Node.prototype
  true
```

Here are some docs for the Node and Element classes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element

Comment: What about `<span data-a="1" >123</span>` ? this span is an element which has it's own node. but does the attribute also has it's own node ?

Comment: the only point I want to clarify is that Node is an interface not a class.
from which a number of DOM API object types inherit. It allows those types to be treated similarly; for example, inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way. 
I found this in mozilla link that you refer to. thanks for precious answer

Comment: What's good about you explanation is to use a simple ordinary thing in an analogy, name it `dog`, `animal`. Reader grabs it right away. Kudo!

Answer (score 13):

Best source of information for all of your DOM woes

https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodes

> Objects implementing the Document, DocumentFragment, DocumentType,
> Element, Text, ProcessingInstruction, or Comment interface (simply
> called nodes) participate in a tree.

https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element

> Element nodes are simply known as elements.

Answer (score 8):

**Node : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp**

The Node object represents a single node in the document tree.
A node can be an element node, an attribute node, a text node, or any other of the node types explained in the Node Types chapter.

**Element : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp**

The Element object represents an element in an XML document. Elements may contain attributes, other elements, or text. If an element contains text, the text is represented in a text-node.

**duplicate :**

- [What's the difference between an element and a node in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132564/whats-the-difference-between-an-element-and-a-node-in-xml)
- [Why are Nodes and Elements different in XML? What was the rationale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190863/what-is-the-difference-between-a-node-and-an-element-in-xml)

Answer (score 6):

Node is used to represent tags in general. Divided to 3 types:

Attribute Note: is node which inside its has attributes. 
Exp: `<p id=”123”></p>`

Text Node: is node which between the opening and closing its have contian text content.
Exp: `<p>Hello</p>`

Element Node : is node which inside its has other tags.
Exp: `<p><b></b></p>`

Each node may be types simultaneously, not necessarily only of a single type.

Element is simply a element node.

Comment: Apart from the last sentence, nothing in this answer is correct. 
1 . A node tree represents "any markup-based resource", a node is a part of it but doesn't have to represent a tag because tags can be omitted.
2. An attribute noDe has nothing "inside" of it, it represents an attribute.
3. A text node represents text. Text doesn't have to be associated with tags but with a node of type TEXT_NODE(3).

Comment: 4. An element node doesn't have to contain anything or it can just contain a comment and/or some text.
5. Each node is of one type and one type only. node.nodeType returns (in general) a number between 1 and 12.
Please improve your answer. For references https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node-trees, https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodes