# Iterate over all node objects not only element objects

Tags: javascript

I've read the following very good article:
[Difference between Node object and Element object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object/)
 as to clear out the difference between a node object and an element object. I 've understood that

> element objects are a subset of node objects.

So, after that I've come upon the following query: In which way may I iterate through all the ***node objects***? By using `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` ,I think I am getting all the ***element objects*** since all of them have value 1 for their `.nodeType` property. Am I right and if yes, how may I include into my results all these nodes that are not elements?

Thank you

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/wmnLahjr/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown that only goes one level - I believe the OP wants _every_ node in the document.

Comment: @Alnitak It won't meant to be an answer, because I have no knowledge on that. It was all I could contribute on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any standard DOM function that will return *every* `Node` (as opposed to `Element`) in the entire document.

You would probably have to use recursive DOM traversal to find them all with something like this:

```
function getAllNodes(parent, nodes) {
    parent = parent || document;
    nodes = nodes || [];

    var child = parent.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        nodes.push(child);
        if (child.hasChildNodes) {
            getAllNodes(child, nodes);
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

As written you can just write `var nodes = getAllNodes()` and it'll automatically start at the document root.

Comment: p.s. this function _doesn't_ include the initial parent in the results

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question. You use `document.getElementsByTagName`. Let me repeat that for you. get**Elements**ByTagName.

Non-element nodes don't have a tag name, an identifier, or anything like that. The only way to designate them is by where they are in the document structure.

You can get a reference to an Element and then browse its childNodes, as has been suggested already.

Another way is to [use an XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate), which, unlike CSS selectors, is able to point directly to any Node, including text and comment Nodes.

```
document.evaluate("*", document.documentElement, null, XPathResult. UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE)
```

Comment: what's the compatibility level required for XPath?

Comment: what a surprise... [not!]