# How to get Element from Node

Tags: javascript, dom

From my understanding, `document.querySelector` returns a `Node` object. I can then call `appendChild` on this object.

I execute the following code to append a bunch of divs to my container div:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
  var block = document.createElement('div');
  block.className = 'block';
  container.appendChild(block);
}
```

And end up with the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  ...
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

How can I loop through each element in my container div and add a new class to it using my existing `container` variable?

I have tried this:

```
...
container.childNodes[i].className = 'myClass';
```

It seems I need to access the `Element` object of the child `Node`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: That should work. What is `i`? Are all of the containers `childnodes` elements? Try `children` instead.

Comment: [difference between node and element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object)

Comment: The nodes returned by `querySelector` are all elements, because you can't write a selector for non-element nodes.

Comment: Why don't you add the class in the loop where you create the DIVs?

Comment: Before you added the DIVs, the container DIV may have had a child text node. Appending the DIVs doesn't get rid of that, so `container.childNodes[0]` may be that text node.

Comment: @Bergi `i` is a number between 0 and 399. When I run `console.log(container.childNodes[i])` the output is `<div class="hover"></div>`. Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node, `children` doesn't seem to be a property or method of `Node`.

@Barmar I didn't know about the text node! And I'm working on this CodePen: http://codepen.io/robkom/pen/RWmodz. I want to randomly loop through and simulate hover on the child elements.

Comment: @cornflakes24: I don't understand, isn't that log expected? What doesn't work? `.children`is a property of the [`Element` subclass of `Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

Comment: I believe: nodes are sometimes elements, and elements are always nodes

Comment: Ah, yes, using `container.children` works, sorry!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To add classes to the elements in the `container` variable, I used the following code:

```
container.children[i].className = 'myClass';
```

I had to use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead of [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes). You can see the context in which this code was used here: http://codepen.io/robkom/pen/RWmodz.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add it when you create the divs ?

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
  var block = document.createElement('div');
  block.className = 'block myClass';
  container.appendChild(block);
}
```

Comment: This is the trivial solution - if I could have done this, I would have (and thus not posted this question on SO).