# why TypeError: par.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, function

I need change style's in `<div>` from `{align, left}` to `{align, right}`

```
function changeAttribute() {
    var gg = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var allP = gg[12].childNodes;
    var par, align;
    for (i = 0; i < allP.length; i++) {
        par = allP[i];
        gAl = par.getAttribute("align");
        if (!gAl) {
            continue
        } else if (gAl == "right") {
            align = par.setAttribute("align", "left");
        }
        align = par.setAttribute("align", "right");
    }
}
```

Comment: cause not all childNodes have that method defined in the prototype? SOme of them might be text, for example. Debugging in dev console ForTheWin

Comment: Seems like your missing an else statement in the end.
align always gets set "right"

Comment: you are right too, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your missing an else statement in the end. 
align always gets set "right".

```
var gg  = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var allP = gg[12].childNodes;

var par, align;
for (i = 0; i < allP.length; i++){
    par = allP[i];
    if (gAl.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) continue;
    gAl = par.getAttribute("align");
    if(!gAl){
        continue
    } else if ( gAl == "right"){
        align = par.setAttribute("align", "left");
    } else {
        align = par.setAttribute("align", "right");
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not answer the question. and it still has the same problem, par.getAttribute  call will fail.

Comment: @VladimirM Why would a <p> tag not have the setAttribute() method defined, since all [DOM Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) have it. [Additionally](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082)

Comment: @Reijo the thing is that you are not getting a list of elements, but a list of nodes. Elements are subset of nodes. you can see more on that difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I'll edit the code, to handle this issue.
That post also says that a nodeList is an  array-like list of nodes.
Of which each node is an Element if all children of gg[12] are of type Element. (see last paragraph before the edit)