# Getting HtmlElement from document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, htmlelements

I want to get Element height from `document`, I am trying get it with `const header = document.getElementsByClassName(myClass)`. But there some problems in conversion of `Element` to `HTMLElement`. Are there some ways for building `HTMLElement` from `string` or getting `attributes` like `offsetHeight` from `HTMLCollection`?

```
const myheader = document.getElementsByClassName(myClass);
console.info(myHeader[0].offsetHeight);
```

Comment: can you post your html code

Comment: Is `myClass` a JS variable or is it the name of the class? If it's the name of class, it needs to have quotation marks. like ('myClass').

Comment: using getComputedStyle I have an error 'Element has an 'any' type because type 'Element' has no index signature

Comment: Maybe it gives you some hints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use something like this to get offset height

```
document.getElementsByClassName('popup')[0].offsetHeight
```