# Typescript: Convert HTMLElement to Node

Tags: javascript, typescript, htmlelements

How can I convert a `HTMLElement` to a `Node` element.

According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9979779/639035 ) a `An element is one specific type of node`... but I cannot find a way to convert them.

I specifically need a Node element, to pass it into a `MutationObserver` (https://nitayneeman.com/posts/listening-to-dom-changes-using-mutationobserver-in-angular/ ), and a `HTMLElement` throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript only provides type definitions for already existing objects, it can't modify the nature of the object. So, your question is about javascript and not about typescript.

Inside the `lib.dom.d.ts` (the type definition library used by Angular), the `MutationObserver` object is not much correctly defined:

```
interface MutationObserver {
    disconnect(): void;
    observe(target: Node, options: MutationObserverInit): void;
    takeRecords(): MutationRecord[];
}
```

where `target` is defined as `Node` element.

`HTMLElement` is defined inside the same file, and it extends `Element` which extends `Node`. So `HTMLElement` shouldn't have any problem to fit inside the target property.

A better type definition would be:

```
observe<T extends Node>(target: T, options: MutationObserverInit): void;
```

But since this type definition hasn't been provided, it would be better if you tell the the compiler that it's perfectly fine just passing `element as Node` inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks, I will create a bug for this later :)

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug, it can also be the intended behaviour

Comment: Maybe but I cannot see a reason for this, so it looks like a big. Beside it wolf be a very small change after all

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do this would be to cast your `HTMLElement` as a `Node`. There are two ways to do this. The first is the `as` syntax.

```
let myNode = theHTMLElement as Node;
```

You can also use the `<>` syntax.

```
let myNode = <Node>theHTMLElement;
```

**Note:** This changes the type *when TypeScript is compiling*, but does not magically give you the JS methods and properties of a `Node`.

It essentially allows you to bypass the type safety when you know you can. TypeScript will do its best to warn you if types are incompatible, but you can still introduce bugs if you are not careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the HTML into a string and then convert the string with this method:

```
const stringHTML = '<div>One</div><div>Two</div>';
const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(stringHTML);
console.log(fragment);
```

Maybe this link will help: [convert-html-stings-dom-nodes](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-html-stings-dom-nodes)

There is also another method called DOM parser. It is explained in the link. Hope it helps.