# What is the difference between between finding element by class name and finding element by CSS selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-selectors

**Class name:**

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("intro");
```

**CSS selector:**

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("p.intro");
```

I'm confused is there is any difference or both are same?

Comment: The first also finds `div`s and other elements with `class="intro"`…!?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is a very old function and will work even before IE8 while querySelectorAll is more or less the later implementation of jQuery's $ function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querySelector and querySelectorAll vs getElementsByClassName and getElementById in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid)

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName("intro");` returns an array of html elements
`document.querySelectorAll("p.intro");` returns an array of nodes

And the difference between elements and nodes is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object)

Answer (score 0):

Class names are one type of CSS Selectors, we also have elements, ids, pseudo selectors and these can be combined in different ways.
See a full list https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

`document.getElementsByClassName` would only let you input class selectors
`document.querySelectorAll` lets you use all and combine them in various ways just as you did with your `p.intro`

As pointed out, you can fine-tune the class selection by using multiple class names if that element possesses all.

Comment: "would only let you input one class selector" not sure what you mean by that. It allows for multiple classes. `document.getElementsByClassName("foo bar baz doo beee dooooo")`

Comment: That is true, I meant in terms of specificity. I would edit that. Thank you