# document.querySelector() returns an element that's not an instance of Node

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm traversing the DOM and one of the divs I analyze looks different than the rest.
All other divs:

```
document.querySelector('#somediv') instanceof Node
// true
```

But one div:

```
document.querySelector('#strange_div') instanceof Node
// false
```

When I check the constructor of that div:

```
document.querySelector('#strange_div').constructor.name
// HTMLDivElement
```

And yet, when I test instanceof again:

```
document.querySelector('#strange_div') instanceof HTMLDivElement
// false
```

How is it possible ? A div that isn't an instance of Node, yet is an instance of HTMLDivElement

**Note**
The div is of type ELEMENT_NODE

```
   document.querySelector('#strange_div').nodeType
   // 1
```

Checking the `__proto__` chain

```
(7) [div#strange, HTMLDivElement, HTMLElement, Element, Node, EventTarget, {…}]
0: div#strange
1: HTMLDivElement {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLDivElement", constructor: ƒ}
2: HTMLElement {…}
3: Element {…}
4: Node {…}
5: EventTarget {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "EventTarget", addEventListener: ƒ, dispatchEvent: ƒ, removeEventListener: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
6: {constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
```

Comparing the Node in the **proto** chain:

```
document.querySelector('#strange').__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Node
// false
```

**Note 2**

My intention here is to override the Node element with a specific getter function. This getter is available to all the divs but the one which isn't an instance of Node.

In more details:
`childNodes` is extended by some 3rd party library and that's why it's unusable to me.
I created a new iframe and I extend the Node element with a pure reference to the `childNodes` getter

```
const ref =
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
        safeReferenceFromIframe.Node.prototype,
        functionName
      ) || {};
    Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, `pure_${functionName}`, ref);
```

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov  but if the div is of type HTMLDivElement wouldn't that make him also an instanceof Node, since it is extended from that? (that's what happens for the other elements)

Comment: Can you share the relevant code from which that element is created and appended to the page?

Comment: Expecting `instanceof` to behave in any predictable manner is a bit of a fool's game imo.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I don't have access to it, but I can say it is done in angular.

Comment: All that the value of the `constructor` property tells us is the value that that property currently has. It's a writable property. You could assign the value `"hello"` to it and it would retain that value. I'm not sure how one would create a functioning DOM node that's not an instance of `Node`, but things like `.constructor`, `instanceof` can be quite unreliable in telling the full story about an object. I would suggest inspecting the div's `__proto__` chain (in a debugger, not production code) to try and figure out how it came into being.

Comment: @JLRishe if ```instanceof``` and ```constructor``` are not reliable, I'm really stuck

Comment: @Yaron Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do and what the actual problem is? That's the only way we can unstick you. Did you take my suggestion and look at the `__proto__` chain?

Comment: @JLRishe I updated the info in the question

Comment: @Yaron Ok, well there's your problem - you're using an antipractice to troubleshoot an antipractice. You generally shouldn't be adding your own stuff to host objects unless it's for something like a polyfill. What is this new method intended to do? Are you trying to use this in production code, or just for fun? And what I meant by checking the `__proto__` chain was not to check just its immediate ancestor, but all of its ancestors. `var o = theDiv;
var protos = [];
do { protos.push(o); o = o.__proto__; } while (o);
console.log(protos);`

Comment: @JLRishe I updated with the full ```__proto__ ``` chain.
I wouldn't extend the Node normally, and indeed it is for a polyfill.

Comment: @Yaron Ok, so the prototype chain shows `Node` in it. I would suggest comparing that to the global `Node` (`protos[4] === Node`) and seeing if they are equal. If not, it may be that the other `Node` is in some other frame or something like that and that is where your `div` is coming from (inheritance and `instanceof` don't work across frames). Still not sure what the solution would be if that's the case. What do you mean by "`childNodes` is sometimes overriden"? `childNodes` is supported since Chrome and Firefox 1 and IE 5. There should be no reason to override or polyfill it.

Comment: @JLRishe updated the info for your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is this possible?

There's no way for me to know exactly why it's happening in your case, but one well-known pitfall of `instanceof` is that it does not work across frames.

The `Node` in one frame is different from the `Node` in another frame. Your page's DOM can contain an element that was created in another frame, and if you use `instanceof` on it, it will not inherit from the `Node` in your page.

Like this:

```js
const ifr = document.querySelector('iframe');

// Create an <a> element using an iframe's content document
const createdA = ifr.contentDocument.createElement('a');
createdA.textContent = "I am a link";
createdA.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";

// append it to the dom
document.body.appendChild(createdA);

// re-retrieve it
const myA = document.querySelector('a');

console.log('myA instanceof Node', myA instanceof Node); // false
console.log(myA.nodeName);                               // A
```

It sounds like you are working within a very chaotic environment - `.childNodes` accessors being overridden, mystery elements that don't inherit from `Node`.

My primary suggestion would be to find a way to remedy that.

If that's not an option, my next suggestion would be to abandon your attempts of modifying the `Node` prototype, and instead create a function that provides the functionality of the built-in `childNodes` property.

Looks like your current approach could be adapted in order to do that:

```js
// Converts a prototype method to a function that takes an instance
// of that type as the first argument, followed by any additional arguments
const unbind = (f) => (that, ...args) => f.apply(that, args);   
    

const childNodesDesc =
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
        ifr.contentWindow.Node.prototype,
        'childNodes'
    );
    
    
const childNodes = unbind(childNodesDesc.get);


// use childNodes
console.log(childNodes(strangeDiv));
```

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborate answer !
Does it follow that:
```strangeDiv.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ (Node)``` necessary equals one of the Node objects either on the main window, or in one of the iframes in the document ?

Comment: @Yaron Probably, though it could also be from an `iframe` that was created and then removed. Or there may also be some other way of creating the situation you're seeing that I just haven't thought about.