# JavaScript-Isn't <td> a Child Node of <tr>?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following code works just fine, and I am able to get the value of the first cell of a selected row:

```js
document.getElementById("tst").onclick = function() {
  var chosen = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
  var myTd = chosen[0].getElementsByTagName('td');
  var rightCell = myTd[0];
  console.log(rightCell.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>table_js_test002.html</title>
  <link href="css/test_table.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="selected">
      <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="tst" value="OK" onclick="fnselect()" />


</body>

</html>
```

This also works:

```
var myTd = chosen[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
```

My question is, from my limited understanding of JavaScript and DOM Node Navigation, isn't `<td>` a child of `<tr>`?  Why can't I get

```
var myTd = chosen[0].firstChild.innerHTML
```

to work?

Comment: Please remove the preamble and references to other users/questions. Ask your question in the most straight forward manner possible, with no back story, and the shortest **runnable example** that reproduces your problem.

Comment: OK.  DIdn't want to steal someone elses code, as simple as this piece of HTML is without giving due credit.

Answer (score 5):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild), when using `firstChild`:

> Any whitespace will create a `#text` node, from a single space to multiple spaces, returns, tabs, and so on.

Just use `firstElementChild`:

```
myTd = chosen[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML
```

Comment: It's worth noting, if you write your HTML all smushed up, `<tr><td>etc</td></tr>`, the TD can be the first child. Just... no one does that, because we like ourselves. The "problem" here is the whitespace in the code, not the API.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `getElementsByTagName` returns a HTMLCollection, not a `NodeList`. Both are array like object but HTMLCollection contain `elements` and `firstChild` only works on `nodes`.

If you want more details about the two

[NodeList vs HTMLCollection](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp#:%7E:text=An%20HTMLCollection%20(previous%20chapter)%20is,list%20(collection)%20of%20objects.)

[Node vs Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object)

Comment: Yes, that part I understand, and, that's why I used the indexes [0] after the collection names.

Comment: chosen[0], should be an element, as is myTd[0].