# Can't assign a value from Input element type 'range' to a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, get, range

everyone.

I'm trying to get the value from an Input element type 'range' and assign it to the variable, but I keep getting 'undefined' type.
Could you, please, advise, why does it happen and how can I assign type 'range' value to a variable?

```
let n;

let range = document.getElementById('range');
range.min = '0';
range.max = '100';
range.step = '1';
range.value = '20';

range.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (this.value > 0 && this.value < 100) {
    n = this.value;  
  }
});

console.log(n);
'undefined'
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your console log is outside of your event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `input` to see the value beeing printed in the `console`.

replace `this` with `range`.

```js
let n;

let range = document.getElementById('range');
range.min = '0';
range.max = '100';
range.step = '1';
range.value = '20';

range.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (range.value > 0 && range.value < 100) {
    n = range.value;  
  }
  console.log(n);
});
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range">
```

`this` is referencing to a `node` (HTML DOM Elements) and `range` to your specified `input`.

Also as @Taplar mentioned `console.log()` has to be inside the function.

More information about `node`s can be found here: [Difference between Node object and Element object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object)

Comment: The catch of the `this` in the arrow function is valid, but the console log is still in the wrong place.

Comment: i got error using `this` on arrow function, that's why i pointed out.

Comment: Francisco and @Taplar - Thank you, very much! Both 'this.value' and 'range.value' work fine for me. The problem was with the incorrect console.log() call. I should have called it in the function, where this variable is actually being used. Also, as I don't have any loop, the same function should have been called out right after 'if' statement in the EventListener.