# How to get Type"Element" through Type"ChildNode"

Tags: typescript

this is my first come here ask questions.

this my code

```
let nb: Element;
    if (sc.hasChildNodes() == true) {
        let lc = sc.lastChild!;
        lc.insertBefore(newButton, lc);
        nb = sc.lastChild!;
    }
```

get error : Type 'ChildNode' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 106 more.

---------- Update ----------

just need to know what is " Type Assertions "

this update code

```
let nb: Element;
    if (sc.hasChildNodes() == true) {
        sc.lastChild!.after(newButton);
        nb = sc.lastChild! as Element;
    }
```

Comment: How about `let nb: Node;`?

Comment: @user3738870 
The reason why I want to use type "Element"
is because I want to use the function "setAttribute()"

Comment: did you try `let lc as Element = ...`?

Comment: @IanCarter sor i dont know what you mean

Comment: Then you have to check if `sc.lastChild` is of type `Element` indeed. Or if you're certain that it's an `Element`, you can do `nb = sc.lastChild! as Element;`. You can see the difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object

Comment: i got it ,
just use "as"

Comment: thank guys , the solution is very simple , just i neglected concept of (Type Assertions)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need all those conditions - you just need to know if you want to use `lastElementChild` or `lastChild` in the following code:

```js
const insertButtonBeforeLastChild = (sc, btn) => sc.lastElementChild && sc.insertBefore(btn, sc.lastElementChild);

insertButtonBeforeLastChild(sc1, document.createElement('button'));
insertButtonBeforeLastChild(sc2, document.createElement('button'));
insertButtonBeforeLastChild(sc3, document.createElement('button'));
insertButtonBeforeLastChild(sc4, document.createElement('button'));
insertButtonBeforeLastChild(sc5, document.createElement('button'));
```

```css
div, button{min-height:1em;margin:5px;display:block;border:1px dotted blue;}
div div{background:#CCC;}
```

```html
<div id="sc1"></div>
<div id="sc2">text</div>
<div id="sc3"><div>onlychild</div></div>
<div id="sc4"><div>first</div><div>second</div></div>
<div id="sc5"><div>first</div><div>second</div>third-text</div>
```

In regards to the question you can generally use `MyNode as Element` to specify the specific type in TS. But your updated code looks like you are trying to do something like this:

```
let nb: Element | null = sc.lastChild ? sc.appendChild(newButton) : null;
```

Comment: my problem actually not complicated ,
really just add "as" can be solved ,
but your grammar more concise ,
i can learn , thank you help .