# Typescript -extend interface Node=HTMLElement

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am using Cypress 10.
I have seen this code:

```
 Cypress.Commands.add(
  'byTestId',
  // Borrow the signature from cy.get
  <E extends Node = HTMLElement>(
    id: string,
    options?: Partial<
      Cypress.Loggable & Cypress.Timeoutable & Cypress.Withinable & Cypress.Shadow
    >,
  ): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<E>> =
    cy.get(`[data-testid="${id}"]`, options),
);
```

What does the `E extends Node = HTMLElement`  means exactly? and can it be replaced by `E extends HTMLElement`
Is there a difference in these two?

Comment: `E` is a generic parameter that defaults to `HTMLElement` if it cannot be inferred.

Comment: @caTS Thanks, can you please put it as a comment so I can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`E extends Node = HTMLElement` is a generic type parameter with a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of `Node`, and if it can't be inferred by the TypeScript compiler, it will default to `HTMLElement`.

For `Node` vs `HTMLElement`, you may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object) question:

> A `node` is the generic name for any type of object in the DOM hierarchy.  A `node` could be one of the built-in DOM elements such as `document` or `document.body`, it could be an HTML tag specified in the HTML such as `<input>` or `<p>` or it could be a text node that is created by the system to hold a block of text inside another element.  So, in a nutshell, a `node` is any DOM object.
>
> An `element` is one specific type of `node` as there are many other types of nodes (text nodes, comment nodes, document nodes, etc...).