# Typescript: How to check if variable is of type Element? ReferenceError: Element is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, xml-parsing, xmldom

I am using Node with TypeScript and the xmldom package to parse an xml file and iterate over it to convert it into JavaScript classes.
For this, I am iterating over childNodes with

```
constructor(xmlElement: Element) {
    for (let childNode of xmlElement.childNodes) {
        if (childNode instanceof Element) {
            if(childNode.tagName=="myTag") { /* do something depending on which tag it is*/ }
            /* a lot of similar if statements */
        }
        else {
            /* do something for text nodes*/
        }
    }
}
```

However running this code gives me the error message: "ReferenceError: Element is not defined". Even though it should exist as a standard class of JavaScript, if I am not mistaken.

Using
`if(childNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)`
as suggested in [9979172](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object/9979779#9979779) throws the error `Node is not defined`. Using `if(childNode.innerHTML)` works logic wise and the code runs as intended, but TypeScript is not able to infer that this is equivalent to `childNode instanceof Element` and marks every if statement using `childNode.tagName` of `childNode.innerHTML` down the line as a TypeScript error and adding `//@ts-ignore` to every second line defeats the purpose of using TypeScript.

I read in a related question that Element probably doesn't exists in Node, because there is no DOM on the server, if that's the case I'm looking for an alternative solution, which doesn't cause TypeScript errors.

Comment: maybe you can look into JSDOM (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)? it's basically a DOM parser that works with Node runtime and it provided a similar if not exact DOM API as a browser would