# What is the difference between children and childNodes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have found myself using JavaScript and I ran across `childNodes` and `children` properties. I am wondering what the difference between them is. Also is one preferred to the other?

Answer (score 469, accepted):

Understand that [`.children`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-parentnode-children) is a property of an [Element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element). <sup>1</sup> Only Elements have `.children`, and these children are all of type Element. <sup>2</sup>

However, [`.childNodes`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-node-childnodes) is a property of [Node](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-node). `.childNodes` can contain any node. <sup>3</sup>

A concrete example would be:

```
let el = document.createElement("div");
el.textContent = "foo";

el.childNodes.length === 1; // Contains a Text node child.
el.children.length === 0;   // No Element children.
```

Most of the time, you want to use `.children` because generally you don't want to loop over [Text](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-text) or [Comment](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-comment) nodes in your DOM manipulation.

If you do want to manipulate Text nodes, you probably want [`.textContent`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-node-textcontent) or [`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) instead. <sup>4</sup>

It's important to understand the distinction between the 2, before deciding which one to use: The `.textContent` property represents the text content of the node **and its descendants** whereas the `.nodeValue` property represents the value of the current node.

---

<sup>1. Technically, it is an attribute of [ParentNode](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode), a mixin included by Element.</sup>
<sup>2. They are all elements because `.children` is a [HTMLCollection](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection), which can only contain elements.</sup>
<sup>3. Similarly, `.childNodes` can hold any node because it is a [NodeList](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist).</sup>
<sup>4. Or [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). See the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText).</sup>

Comment: Yeah, IE seems to have some problems: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71

Comment: Actually, children is a property of the parentnode interface, not element. http://usonsci.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/html-children-vs-childnodes/

Comment: Seems iOS 8.3 (maybe others?) **doesn't support `.children` on XML documents**: http://jsfiddle.net/fbwbjvch/1/

Comment: Only had trouble with this on Microsoft Edge with XML nodes. It appears Microsoft Edge doesn't like children. That's good, I wouldn't want that browser reproducing.

Comment: Natural follow-up of "element vs. node": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132564/whats-the-difference-between-an-element-and-a-node-in-xml

Answer (score 35):

[`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children) returns only **element** children, while [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes) returns all **node** children.  Note that elements are nodes, so both are available on elements.

I believe `childNodes` is more reliable.  For example, MDC (linked above) notes that IE only got `children` right in IE 9.  `childNodes` provides less room for error by browser implementors.

Comment: Darn, if only this worked on IE 6-8, it would be a dream come true.

Comment: @minitech it does work (for some value of work). Apparently `.children` doesn't filter out comment nodes, but it filters out text nodes.

Comment: @Raynos: Exactly - same with `.getElementsByTagName('*')`. IE can be so annoying sometimes...

Comment: There are shim/polyfill implementations of `children` that support IE.

Answer (score 13):

Good answers so far, I want to only add that you could check the type of a node using `nodeType`:

`yourElement.nodeType`

This will give you an integer: (taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType))

```
| Value |             Constant             |                          Description                          |  |
|-------|----------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|--|
|    1  | Node.ELEMENT_NODE                | An Element node such as <p> or <div>.                         |  |
|    2  | Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE              | An Attribute of an Element. The element attributes            |  |
|       |                                  | are no longer implementing the Node interface in              |  |
|       |                                  | DOM4 specification.                                           |  |
|    3  | Node.TEXT_NODE                   | The actual Text of Element or Attr.                           |  |
|    4  | Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE          | A CDATASection.                                               |  |
|    5  | Node.ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE       | An XML Entity Reference node. Removed in DOM4 specification.  |  |
|    6  | Node.ENTITY_NODE                 | An XML <!ENTITY ...> node. Removed in DOM4 specification.     |  |
|    7  | Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE | A ProcessingInstruction of an XML document                    |  |
|       |                                  | such as <?xml-stylesheet ... ?> declaration.                  |  |
|    8  | Node.COMMENT_NODE                | A Comment node.                                               |  |
|    9  | Node.DOCUMENT_NODE               | A Document node.                                              |  |
|   10  | Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE          | A DocumentType node e.g. <!DOCTYPE html> for HTML5 documents. |  |
|   11  | Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE      | A DocumentFragment node.                                      |  |
|   12  | Node.NOTATION_NODE               | An XML <!NOTATION ...> node. Removed in DOM4 specification.   |  |
```

Note that according to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType):

> The following constants have been deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore: Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE, Node.ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE, Node.ENTITY_NODE, Node.NOTATION_NODE