# How to get < span > value？

Tags: javascript

There are a piece of code,but can not use `<id>` tag.

So,how do I get to the `<span> 1 2 3 4`?

```
<div id="test">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
<div>
```

Comment: using plain javascript or jquery?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer javascript

Comment: What do you want to get exactly? All the values of each span, or just the value of a particular span? Side note, `id` is not a tag, but an attribute of the tag `div` (in your case).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this

```
var div = document.getElementById("test");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
  alert(spans[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var test = document.getElementById( 'test' );

// To get the text only, you can use "textContent"
console.log( test.textContent ); // "1 2 3 4"
```

`textContent` is the standard way. `innerText` is the property to use for legacy IE. If you want something as cross browser as possible, recursively use `nodeValue`.

Answer (score 7):

No jQuery tag, so I'm assuming pure JavaScript

```
var spanText = document.getElementById('targetSpanId').innerText;
```

Is what you need

But in your case:

```
var spans = document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('span');//returns node-list of spans
for (var i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
    console.log(spans[i].innerText);//logs 1 for i === 0, 2 for i === 1 etc
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hWeX/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="test">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
<div id="test2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var getDiv = document.getElementById('test');
    var getSpan = getDiv.getElementsByTagName('span');​​​
    var divDump = document.getElementById('test2');

    for (var i=0; i<getSpan.length; i++) {
        divDump.innerHTML = divDump.innerHTML + ' ' + getSpan[i].innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript would be like this

```
var children = document.getElementById('test').children;
```

If you are using jQuery it would be like this

```
$("#test").children()
```

Comment: `childNodes` is different than `children`.

Comment: sorry my bad should be `document.getElementById('test').children` as I want the property of an Elemnt not a Node property.

Comment: It's not about properties :) Using `childNodes` will get you the nodes in it, so the textnodes, the comments, etc. Using `children`, you only get the *element* children. Edit your answer to correct this :-)

Comment: Yeah it's true, but I was thinking about the difference between children and childNodes (and why you will get all the text and comments :) . Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelectorAll to get all span elements and then use new ES2015 (ES6) spread operator convert StaticNodeList that querySelectorAll returns to array of spans, and then use map operator to get list of items.

See example bellow

```js
([...document.querySelectorAll('#test span')]).map(x => console.log(x.innerHTML))
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to change your code as below:-**

```
<html>
<body>

<span id="span_Id">Click the button to display the content.</span>

<button onclick="displayDate()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function displayDate() {
   var span_Text = document.getElementById("span_Id").innerText;
   alert (span_Text);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**After doing this you will get the  tag value in alert.**

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = document.getElementById( 'test' ).innerHTML;
```

It will work better