# Can plotly use a dynamic html table as source data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, plotly, r-markdown

If I have an html table that contains values that are calculated based on filters within my file, can I get plotly to read and produce a plot based on those values?

I'm not sure that it matters to answering this question, but I use R primarily, and use the r code chunks calculate sums from a sharedData object names shared_ert that I created with the `crosstalk` package for R.

````
<table id="example" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Enrolled</th>
<th>Not Enrolled</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
```{r, echo=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
summarywidget::summarywidget(shared_ert,statistic = 'sum',column = 'Enrolled')
```
</td>
<td>

```{r, echo=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
summarywidget::summarywidget(shared_ert,statistic = 'sum',column = 'Not Enrolled')

```

</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

**Note that summary widget ends up producing a span tag within each td.**
The spans look like `<span id ="waffle" class="summarywidget html-widget html-widge-static-bound">1293</span>`

So the table ends up looking like:

```
<table id="example" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Enrolled</th>
<th>Not Enrolled</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span id ="waffle" class="summarywidget html-widget html-widge-static-bound">1293</span>
<script type="application/json" data-for="waffle">
### a bunch of data appears here, from which the 1293 value is derived
</script>

</td>
<td>
<span id ="iron" class="summarywidget html-widget html-widge-static-bound">948</span>
<script type="application/json" data-for="iron">
### a bunch of data appears here, from which the 948 value is derived
</script>


</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

From my limited understanding of the world of javascript, I need my data to look something like

```
var data = [
{
x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
y: [20, 14, 23],
type: 'bar'
  }
];
```

So that I can get a plot produced with something like:

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

(directly from https://plotly.com/javascript/bar-charts/)

If I understand the problem correctly, I need to read the html table `example` and create a `var` that holds the table.  After much searching around SO and the web in general, my guess is that the solution here: [HTML Table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271856/html-table-to-json) pulls the table into the correct format.  I'm trying

````
```{js}
function tableToJson(table) {
var data = [];

// first row needs to be headers
var headers = [];
for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
}

// go through cells
for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

    var tableRow = table.rows[i];
    var rowData = {};

    for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

        rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

    }

    data.push(rowData);
}       

return data;
}

var tabdata = $document.getElementById('#example').tableToJSON();            

```
````

I think from here, I need plotly to read the data from the table in it's current state, so I produce the plot using a button and onclick, as follows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Plotly.newPlot('myDiv',tabdata);">Make Plot</button>
```

Upon clicking, the plotly plot appears, but doesn't have a data point anywhere.

I might be way off track in my methodology, so I defer to the original question: can I get plotly to read and produce a plot based on a dynamic html table?

Any help establishing a means to this end would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need generate your json with keys `x` & `y` .So , here `x` value will be your header i.e : `th` tags and `y` values will be `td`values . Now , if you have only one row in your table you can simply create *JSON Object* and then push value inside this using key i.e : *data["x"] , data["y"]*..etc .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function tableToJSON(table) {
  var data = {}; //create obj
  data["x"] = [] //for x & y
  data["y"] = []
  data["type"] = "bar"
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    data["x"].push(table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().trim()); //push x values
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var tableRow = table.rows[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
      data["y"].push(parseInt(tableRow.cells[j].querySelector(".summarywidget").textContent.trim()));
      //push y values
      console.log(tableRow.cells[j].querySelector(".summarywidget").textContent.trim())
    }
  }

  return data;
}

function draw() {
  var tabdata = tableToJSON(document.getElementById('example'));
  tester = document.getElementById('tester');
  Plotly.newPlot(tester, [tabdata])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Enrolled</th>
    <th>Not Enrolled</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="waffle" class="summarywidget html-widget html-widge-static-bound">1293</span>
      <script type="application/json" data-for="waffle">
        ###
        a bunch of data appears here, from which the 1293 value is derived
      </script>

    </td>
    <td>
      <span id="iron" class="summarywidget html-widget html-widge-static-bound">948</span>
      <script type="application/json" data-for="iron">
        ###
        a bunch of data appears here, from which the 948 value is derived
      </script>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="draw()">Make Plot</button>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

---

Now , if you have mutliple rows in your table  you need to generate *JSON Array* of that values .For that you need to keep `main_array` and then push values inside this main_array on each iterations.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function tableToJSON(table) {
  var main_array = [] //for main array
  var for_x = [] //for x values
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    for_x.push(table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().trim()); //push value 
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var tableRow = table.rows[i];
    var data = {}; //create obj..
    data["y"] = [] //for y values
    for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
      data["y"].push(parseInt(tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML.trim())); //push y values
    }
    //save other values..
    data["x"] = for_x
    data["type"] = "bar"
    data["name"] = "Rows" + i
    main_array.push(data) //push values in main array
  }
  //console..[{},{}..]
  return main_array;

}

function draw() {
  var tabdata = tableToJSON(document.getElementById('example'));
  tester = document.getElementById('tester');
  //pass it here
  Plotly.newPlot(tester, tabdata, {
    barmode: 'stack'
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Enrolled</th>
    <th>Not Enrolled</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      123
    </td>
    <td>
      125
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      121
    </td>
    <td>
      127
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="draw()">Make Plot</button>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

Comment: This does a great job with reading an plotting the html table!  In my code, each <td> has a <span> within it, and I *think* that is keeping the plot from displaying properly.  I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051898/how-to-get-span-value, but don't know how to apply it and strip out the spans. Could you please edit the function to strip the <span> tags so that the tableToJSON() function will read just the values?

Comment: I edited the question with a better look at how the `<td>` contents looks when I inspect it. There's also a `<script>` bit in each one.

Comment: Hi, see first example i have updated that with your html .

Comment: Is it possible to do this in R? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453274/can-plotly-use-a-datatable-as-source-data