# Ordered List Iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to allow me to iterate through an ordered list similar in functionality as table.rows? I am using Javascript.

The reason I ask this is because I have an ordered list that contains another ordered list inside. I just want to return the parent list items and not the child.

```
<ol id="pList">
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>
        <ol id="cList">
            <li>A's Child 1</li>
            <li>A's Child 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
    <li>Item D</li>
</ol>
```

I now use getElementsbyTag and that returns all li's including the one in cList. I just want the ones in pList.

Thanks

FYI: I would prefer it done in Javascript. The code has to work within Greasemonkey. I don't really know much about jquery and I am not really much of a javascript programmer.

Comment: Are you asking just for vanilla Javascript or you can use jQuery?

Comment: you want 'plain' javascript or you can use jquery?

Comment: Just for fun, let's assume that a question that's *not tagged* [tag:jquery] doesn't *want* a jQuery answer.

Comment: Javascript. I don't know much about jquery and also it has to work in Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-58056027) property that gives you direct access to the `<li>` children of an `<ol>`.

However it is very easy to enumerate them, particularly when you consider that the only legal children of an `<ol>` must be white space text nodes and `<li>` nodes.

```
var ol = document.getElementById('pList');
var li = [];
var node = ol.firstChild;
while (node) {
    if (node.tagType === 3 && node.tagName === 'LI') {
        li.push(node);
    }
    node = node.nextSibling;
}
```

At the end of which, the array `li` contains the required children.

The above code will work in any browser.  The `.children` collection has problems on older versions of MSIE, and `querySelectorAll` is even more modern (and therefore less widely supported).

Comment: What about `var li = document.getElementById('pList').children;`

Comment: @Ghommey `.children` has "odd" behaviour on older versions of MSIE.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript

Comment: And `.childNodes`? Or are we referring to the same thing here?

Comment: I was hoping there was an iterator. Guess this is as good as any

Answer (score 1):

If using [`querySelectorAll()`](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)* is an option for you, it's easy:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll( '#pList > li' );
```

* *note: it's a native DOM method, and has nothing to do with jQuery*

Comment: Nice. Will use it next time as the OLs do not always have ids in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a table of immediate children in every javascript object :

```
document.getElementById('pList').children
```

You can even iterate through it and check whatever your need :

```
var el = document.getElementById('pList');
for (var i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
    if (el.children[i].tagName == "LI") {
        el.children[i].doWhatever();
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript

Comment: I was hoping there was direct access like table.rows. So I guess old fashioned way will do.