# why I can't get the name of the desired tag of this xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I try to get the name of the  child nodes of the **head - > text node** (so I need 
Buut when I write

```
var headerstyles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("style")[0].childNodes; 

   for (i=0;i<headerstyles.length;i++) 
   {
        alert (headerstyles[i].nodeName);

   }
```

I get te response **#text   color  #text  font #text**

So I don't understand whuy before seeing the actual NodeName i get this **#text**
and how can I solve this.

Here is my code

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","desc.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    alert (xmlDoc);




     var headerstyles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("style")[0].childNodes; 

   for (i=0;i<headerstyles.length;i++) 
   {
        alert (headerstyles[i].nodeName);

   }
```

Here is my desc.xml

```
<docs>
 <main>
   <bgrnd>
     <img> </img>
     <color> </color>
   </bgrnd>

   <head>
     <text>Learning about Birds</text>
     <style>
       <color>red</color>
       <font>italic bold 30px Georgia,serif</font>

     </style>
   </head>


   <text>
     <link>  
       <l>   
         <dscrpt>Lesson 1 - Diet and feeding; Water and Drinking</dscrpt>
         <hrf> diet.html </hrf>
       </l>

       <l>
         <dscrpt>Lesson 2 - Feather Care </dscrpt>
         <hrf> feather.html  </hrf>
       </l>

       <l>
         <dscrpt>Lesson 3  - Level three  </dscrpt>
         <hrf> item3.html  </hrf>
       </l>

     </link> ... and so on
```

............................................

Comment: There is a line break after the `<style>` tag. That's a text node. Every line break (and the spaces at the beginning of the following line) form a text node. The node name of text nodes is `#text`.

Comment: Thank you Felix - that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

the **#text** refer to the text node. In your case, you would use `children` rather than `childNodes`.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","desc.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    alert (xmlDoc);




     var headerstyles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("style")[0].children; 

   for (i=0;i<headerstyles.length;i++) 
   {
        alert (headerstyles[i].nodeName);

   }
```

see different between children and child nodes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript)