# Difference between javascript .childNodes & .children

Tags: javascript, parent-child, nodes

I have been working with javascript for a week now. I am currently working on making things work/change through nodes. But I have been noticing something strange, well for an unskilled javascripter it is.

I have a structure in my site like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>....</title>
    <link/>
    <script></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div 1>
        <div 2></div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to find a childnode with the next function:

```
var headerBox = document.body.childNodes;
var txt = "";

for (var x = 0; x < headerBox.length; x ++) {
txt =txt+"Childnode["+x+"]: "+headerBox[x].localName+" ("+headerBox[x].className+")<br>";
}

var x = document.getElementById(box);
x.innerHTML = txt;
```

I get a list with a couple of undefined "NULL" coupled with the reali DIV's

But when I simply change the "document.body.childNodes" to "document.body.children" everything comes uit perfectly, the "NULL" values even change.

What I am wondering is what does the "NULL" values represent in the HTML file, since there are no elements at where the "NULL" value is standing. In my head it is giving me a representation of something that is not there, visible, but yet it is...

Could anyone please explain to me what is going on?

Ps: I am sorry for maybe reposting this but I couldn't find a suitable other question regarding this matter!

Pss: Found a repost ([What is the difference between children and childNodes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript?rq=1)). But it is not answering why it still recognizes unseen childnodes as undefined.

Comment: It doesn't see them as `undefined`. It sees their `.className` property as `undefined`, since text nodes don't have classes.

Comment: But the thing is. There is no text :(.... It's basically the next row. There's not even a blank space between them

Comment: I see plenty of blank space between around the `div` child of `document.body`.

Comment: Soo is it safe to say that javascript sees white space as a childNode??

Comment: IE8 and lower didn't, but W3 compliant browsers do. Everything in your valid markup will be represented in the DOM. FYI, you can use the `.nodeName` property to see what type of node you have. A text node will show `#text`, while an element will give the uppercase tag name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`childNodes` will give you all kinds of nodes while `children` will give you only element nodes. You can use `nodeType` to check what kind of node the current node is:

```
document.body.childNodes[0].nodeType
```

This will give you an integer:

```
1   ELEMENT_NODE
2   ATTRIBUTE_NODE
3   TEXT_NODE
4   CDATA_SECTION_NODE
5   ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE
6   ENTITY_NODE
7   PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE
8   COMMENT_NODE
9   DOCUMENT_NODE
10  DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE
11  DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE
12  NOTATION_NODE
```

As you can see, using `childNodes` will give you a list, that contains text nodes (even if they are filled with whitespaces), comments and all kinds of other node types, you probably don't have to worry too much about.