# Find corresponding node in an identical DOM tree - what is the average and worse time complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, tree

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779438/dom-tree-traversal) posted on here years ago about an interview question where given a node from a DOM tree, we need to find the node in the same position from an identical DOM tree.

Here is the an iterative solution I came up with

```js
const findCorrespondingNode = (rootA, rootB, nodeA) => {
  let currentNode = nodeA;
  const path = [];
  while (currentNode !== rootA) {
    const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(
      currentNode.parentElement.children,
      currentNode
    );
    path.push(index);
    currentNode = currentNode.parentElement;
  }
  currentNode = rootB;
  while (path.length) {
    currentNode = currentNode.children[path.pop()];
  }

  return currentNode;
}
```

Basically I just walk backwards from the target to root, creating the reverse path. The reverse path is an array where each element is the child index of a node.
Travel down the path from rootB to target, popping off the next index until the path array is empty. Finally we return the pointer to the target node.

My question is:

1. what is the (average) time complexity for this solution? The worse case is easy since we need to visit each node once so it is going to be `O(n)`, `n` being the number of DOM nodes in the DOM tree. I think it happens when we have two linked lists and the target node is the last node in each linked list. **The confusion part for me is that** for each level we are also calling `Array.prototype.indexOf` to get the index, and this might take up to `O(D)`, D being the tree's diameter and for a leaf node it is going to take `O((some-constant)n)` to get the index. **, More importantly,** what is the **average** time complexity? We are traversing a tree twice. It seems like it is going to be the height or the depth of the tree. If it is a completely balanced tree, the height of the tree is going to be `logN`. Does that mean the average time complexity is `logN`?
2. If I write the solution using a recursive DFS approach, where we traverse both trees simultaneously, i.e.

```js
const findCorrespondingNode = (rootA, rootB, target) => {
  if(rootA === target) {
    return rootB;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < rootA.children.length; i++) {
    const foundNode = findCorrespondingNode(rootA.children[i], rootB.children[i], target);
    if(foundNode) return foundNode;
  }
}
```

What is the time complexity in this case? Still worse case `O(n)` and average/best case `O(logN)`. Is this recursive approach better than the iterative approach in terms of time complexity since we wouldn't need to do `indexOf` for each level?

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote or downvote this question. On one hand, kind of interesing. On the otherhand, probably not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the (average) time complexity for this solution?

It is O(min(d.logn, n)) where *d* is the (maximum) branching factor of the nodes (2 for binary trees). The `indexOf` call is responsible for this coefficient. However, even if *d* is large, the nodes that are scanned during `indexOf` are never visited again, so the time complexity is also O(n) (as an upper bound). For relatively smaller *d* (in comparison with *n*), O(d.logn) better expresses the time complexity. To cover both extremes we can say: O(min(d.logn, n)). This expresses the fact that if *d* approaches *n*, then necessarily *logn* becomes small (the tree's height diminishes).

> The worse case is easy since we need to visit each node once so it is going to be O(n), n being the number of DOM nodes in the DOM tree. I think it happens when we have two linked lists and the target node is the last node in each linked list.

True.

> The confusion part for me is that for each level we are also calling `Array.prototype.indexOf` to get the index, and this might take up to O(D), D being the tree's diameter and for a leaf node it is going to take O((some-constant)n) to get the index.

The diameter is not concerned here. The complexity of `indexOf` depends on the number of *siblings*. In the case of a degenerate tree that really is a linked list (as you wrote), *D* is 1, i.e. none of the nodes have siblings, and so `indexOf` is always called on an array with just one element: `indexOf` takes constant time in that case.

> We are traversing a tree twice.

A factor of 2 is irrelevant for deriving a time complexity.

> It seems like it is going to be the height or the depth of the tree. If it is a completely balanced tree, the height of the tree is going to be logN. Does that mean the average time complexity is logN?

Yes. Even "almost" balanced trees, like AVL-trees, red-black trees, ... still give this logarithmic time complexity. If you create a tree randomly, it is expected that it will be rather balanced, and its height is O(logN).

> If I write the solution using a recursive DFS approach, where we traverse both trees simultaneously, [...] What is the time complexity in this case?

Here you don't make use of the `parent` links, and so in the worst case you may have to visit each node. This makes it O(n).

> Is this recursive approach better than the iterative approach in terms of time complexity since we wouldn't need to do `indexOf` for each level?

The `indexOf` strategy isn't that bad if *d* is much smaller than *n*. If however we have no idea at all whether that is the case, then the worst-case time complexity is the same -- O(n).

If *d* is much smaller than *n*, then the first algorithm has a better time complexity, O(d.logn).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Just wanted to ask one follow up question: if it is a non binary tree, e.g. N-ary tree so say, the number of children can be up to 10, in which case the height of this tree is still `logn` (n is the total number of nodes) instead of `logmN` (m is branching factor which is 10? and N is the total number of nodes) ? I always thought `logn` is under the assumption that it is a binary tree.

Comment: In big-O notation the base of the logarithm is irrelevant. O(log₂n) = O(log₁₀n), and so you can just write O(logn).

Comment: thanks for the clarification! just another quick question. if space complexity, is it true that iterative approach using parent pointer still wins as it is O(1) while dfs is going to be `logn` since the amount of stack frames in the call stack for dfs traversing is the going to be height/depth of the tree?

Comment: Yes, that is true.