# Get pure text from HTML before a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a editor with some text in html like following:

> <div>Hi<p>Hello</p>bye</div>

Expected result :

> div : Hi

So here i need only text before a tag. Tried using $(div).text() but it gives Hi Hello Bye, whereas i need only text before a tag.
Can anyone help me how to write the javascript function? Thank you.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aWUnASa/3/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var div = document.getElementsByTagName ("div") [0];
 alert (div.childNodes[0].data );//Hi
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ME8mQ/1/)

Comment: This answer is great because [Text nodes](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-text) can be [their own node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) , more on [`childNodes` vs `children`, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

`previousSibling` should do the work for you here, like this:

```js
$('p')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FrNc2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](http://jsbin.com/aWUnASa/3/edit)

Add `div` to the Hi and set an `id` to this `div`

```
<body onload="myFunction();">
  <div id="div1"><div id="div2">Hi</div><p>Hello</p>bye</div>
</body>

function myFunction()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("div1").tagName;
  var y = document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML;
  var z = x + " : " + y;
  alert(z);
  var a = document.getElementById("div1");
  a.innerHTML = z;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to wrap everything in divs'

Comment: You're still wrapping `Hi` in a div, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try:

```
var $temp = $('<div>Hi<p>Hello</p>bye</div>');
$temp.find('p').replaceWith(function(){return "________"});
//it return:  <div>Hi________bye</div>
var text = $temp.text().split('________')[0];
//return: Hi
```

Comment: @HarshVora why not? In generic way: just change find('p') to find('*')

Comment: according to this need to code for all html tags like you have done for <P>