# Getting DOM element information from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I'm trying to grab some attributes of a div table from the DOM from within a script - and failing.

Code should speak for itself:

```
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "SCRIPT_IN_QUESTION.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
      <div id = "my_elements">

            <!-- I want to access 'attribute-one' data attributes from 
                 all children -->
            <div data-attribute-one = "Hello"></div>
            <div data-attribute-one = "World"></div>
      </div>       

</body>
```

I've seen how this is done with an embedded script in the DOM using something along the lines of:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">

      var values  = document.getElementById('my_elements').childNodes;

      var foo = values[0].getAttribute('data-attribute-one');

 </script>
```

I'm trying to access these attributes from within a script that isn't embedded into the DOM, and getAttribute is undefined - guess you can only ue that within the DOM.

How do I access this data in a script 'outside' the DOM?

As the below comment states, doing this after the DOM has been loaded makes sense to do, and I'm doing it something like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', onload, false);


function onload(){

    var data = document.getElementById('canvas_segments').childNodes;

    //This throws an undefined error
    var attribute = data[0].getAttribute('data-attribute-one'); 
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: What if you put your `<script type = "text/javascript" src = "SCRIPT_IN_QUESTION.js"></script>` *after* div definitions? If that's not an option, you may want to put the code into body.onload/window.onload events

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment!, that is actually exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Unless your SCRIPT_IN_QUESTION.js has a function in it that keeps your code from running after the DOM is loaded, there is your problem. Your JavaScript code runs as soon as you hit that `<script>` tag in the header. Therefore, the elements in the DOM don't exist at that point. Do what @YuriyGalanter said and move your tag to the end of the body.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll probably go with setting the tag after the div's. Just curious as to what i'm doing wrong considering i'm executing it after the 'load' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` (which also includes text nodes). And you may need to wrap your call into onload event, e.g.

```
<body onload="onLoad()";>
      <div id = "my_elements">

            <!-- I want to access 'attribute-one' data attributes from 
                 all children -->
            <div data-attribute-one = "Hello"></div>
            <div data-attribute-one = "World"></div>
      </div>       

</body>
```

and in your script:

```
function onLoad() {
   var values  = document.getElementById('my_elements').children;
   var foo = values[0].getAttribute('data-attribute-one');
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank-you again for your time! Using .childNodes was the problem.

Comment: Or if there is need to use '.childNodes', then you should check the 'nodeType' property of each node and check if there is no text nodes you try to process

Answer (score 1):

You have a timing issue here. The script in question is being executed before the DOM is complete, so there is no element.

Either you can move the script tag to the bottom of the page, after all other markup, or you can put the code in a `window.onload` function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the code snippet above, you are attaching the javascript before the DOM structure is loaded. Attach the js file after body so that the HTML content gets loaded first and then the js executes.

**After you have done this you will still hit an issue saying, 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.'** This will be because **you are using 'ChildNodes' instead of 'Children.'** The difference between the two is that Children gets only Elements whereas 'ChildNodes' will fetch nodes too. Refer this question for a clearer distinction between the two ([What is the difference between children and childNodes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript))

You might be interested in a working copy of your code: http://goo.gl/HonxtJ