# forEach is not a function error with JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm trying to make a simple loop:

```
const parent = this.el.parentElement
console.log(parent.children)
parent.children.forEach(child => {
  console.log(child)
})
```

But I get the following error:

> VM384:53 Uncaught TypeError: parent.children.forEach is not a function

Even though `parent.children` logs:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Note: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swb12kqn/1/).

Comment: Same problem occurs with element.siblings

Comment: @Daut yes because element.siblings returns an HTMLCollection and HTMLCollections do not have the forEach() method

Comment: hey you, google searcher! if you're reading this double check that it's forEach with a capital E instead of foreach....

Comment: I ended up using a for loop.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

## First option: invoke forEach indirectly

The `parent.children` is an Array like object. Use the following solution:

```js
const parent = this.el.parentElement;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.children, child => {
  console.log(child)
});
```

The `parent.children` is `NodeList` type, which is an Array like object because:

- It contains the `length` property, which indicates the number of nodes
- Each node is a property value with numeric name, starting from 0: `{0: NodeObject, 1: NodeObject, length: 2, ...}`

See more details in [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/foreach-iterate-array-javascript/#6-iterate-array-like-objects-using-foreach).

---

## Second option: use the iterable protocol

`parent.children` is an `HTMLCollection`: which implements the [iterable protocol](https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-three-dots-changed-javascript/#5-spread-operator-and-iteration-protocols). In an ES2015 environment, you can use the `HTMLCollection` with any construction that accepts iterables.

Use `HTMLCollection` with the spread operatator:

```js
const parent = this.el.parentElement;

[...parent.children].forEach(child => {
  console.log(child);
});
```

Or with the `for..of` cycle (which is my preferred option):

```js
const parent = this.el.parentElement;

for (const child of parent.children) {
  console.log(child);
}
```

Comment: When I use your solution I have no more problems, but the code inside the anonymized function is not executed. .so..

Comment: Which browser to you use so that parent.children tells you that it is a nodeList. On Firefox, it tells me is an HTMLCollection. If it was a nodeList, .forEach() would work

Answer (score 190):

`parent.children` is not an array. It is HTMLCollection and it does not have `forEach` method. You can convert it to the array first. For example in ES6:

```
Array.from(parent.children).forEach(child => {
    console.log(child)
});
```

or using spread operator:

```
[...parent.children].forEach(function (child) {
    console.log(child)
});
```

Comment: I prefer this solution much more than messing with the Array prototype.

Comment: And this answer is (one of) the correct answers to the OPs question. parent.children is an HTMLCollection which do not have a .forEach method

Comment: I used `Array.from(selected_rows).forEach(item => console.log(item));` in my case and it works

Answer (score 35):

A more *naive* version, at least you're sure that it'll work on all devices, without conversion and ES6 :

```
const children = parent.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    console.log(children[i]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/swb12kqn/5/

Comment: Upvoted because all these new ES6 functions do exactly the same good old thing that were a available, but in a messy way, as always with JS

Comment: This is way better solution tbh. Its close to other programming languages and has less of a chance for weird JS weirdness. Its simple, no funky things

Answer (score 25):

`parent.children` will return a <strike>node list</strike> list, technically a [html Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children#Value). That is an array like object, but not an array, so you cannot call array functions over it directly. At this context you can use `Array.from()` to convert that into a real array,

```
Array.from(parent.children).forEach(child => {
  console.log(child)
})
```

Comment: Nope, parent.children does not return a nodeList but an HTML Collection. Not the same thing. If it was a nodeList, .forEach would work

Answer (score 10):

`parent.children` is a `HTMLCollection` which is array-like object. First, you have to convert it to a real `Array` to use `Array.prototype` methods.

```
const parent = this.el.parentElement
console.log(parent.children)
[].slice.call(parent.children).forEach(child => {
  console.log(child)
})
```

Comment: Or don't convert it, but use use .call() on .forEach()?

Comment: @nnnnnn See my answer below.

Comment: There are many ways to convert array-like object to an Array :) This is one of it

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov You don't need to convert it - JavaScript is a duck typing language. Just use this feature.

Answer (score 9):

You can check if you typed **forEach** correctly, if you typed **foreach** like in other programming languages it won't work.

Comment: tldr: the function is case-sensitive

Answer (score 7):

There is **no need for the `forEach`**, you can iterate using only the [`from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)'s second parameter, like so:

```js
let nodeList = [{0: [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':3}]},{1:[]}]
Array.from(nodeList, child => {
  console.log(child)
});
```

Comment: The sad news is that parent.children is not a nodeList... .from() won't work.

Comment: @Cedric if your object is not a NodeList, then you should ask a new question specifically for addressing it. In here, downvoting is used when the answer is intrinsically wrong or harmful and, as you may see by the code snippet, all the elements of the object are iterated and printed, which was the goal of the OP's question.

Comment: Yep, the problem is that the OP's question related to an HTML Collection, not a nodeList... So the answer was simply not answering the question

Comment: @Cedric this answer will also iterate over an HTML Collection since `Array.from` converts the object given in the first parameter into an array. The result is the same as in [madox2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970005/1326147) without needing an extra `forEach` loop ([`Array.from` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) docs).

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to loop over a `NodeList` like this:

```
const allParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
```

I highly recommend loop it this way:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(allParagraphs , function(el) {
    // Write your code here
})
```

Personally, I've tried several ways but most of them didn't work as I wanted to loop over a `NodeList`, but this one works like a charm, give it a try!

*The `NodeList` isn't an Array, but we treat it as an Array, using `Array.` So, you need to know that it is not supported in older browsers!*

Need more information about `NodeList`? Please read its [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: This answer obviously works on nodeList. The trouble is parent.children returns an HTML Collection, which is not a nodeList...

Answer (score 5):

That's because `parent.children` is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), and it doesn't support the `.forEach` method (as NodeList is an array like structure but not an array), so try to call it by first converting it to array using

```
var children = [].slice.call(parent.children);
children.forEach(yourFunc);
```

Comment: No, it is not a NodeList, it is an HTML Collection

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using features of ES6 ([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), you may also simply use a [for loop](http://es6-features.org/#IteratorForOfOperator) like this:

```js
for(let child of [{0: [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':3}]},{1:[]}]) {
  console.log(child)
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. What a contortion, the ES6 syntax, though... Makes me want to cry, and I'm coming from a C++ background...

Answer (score 1):

## use JSON.parse()

```
str_json = JSON.parse(array);
str_json.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details like the reason why the proposed code is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `childNodes` instead of `children`, `childNodes` is also more reliable considering browser compatibility issues, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935720):

```
parent.childNodes.forEach(function (child) {
    console.log(child)
});
```

or using spread operator:

```
[...parent.children].forEach(function (child) {
    console.log(child)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for object try this:

```
  Object.keys(yourObj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key, yourObj[key]);
  });
```