# Error on JS 'body.forEach is not a function'

Tags: javascript, github

I'm kind of new to JS and I can't solve this problem, so I hope you can help me.
I will explain shortly what the situation is, I installed the app Homebridge from Github on my Raspberry: https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge

Installation was successful, so, so far so good. But then I installed the plugin eWeLink for the Homebridge app: https://github.com/gbro115/homebridge-ewelink the installation went good as well, but on the startup there seems to be a probleem in the index.js from the plugin, I get the following output:

> [2018-5-31 23:10:37] [eWeLink] A total of [0] accessories were loaded from the local cache [2018-5-31 23:10:37] [eWeLink] Requesting
>   a list of devices from eWeLink HTTPS API at
>   [https://eu-ota.coolkit.cc:8080] [2018-5-31 23:10:37] Homebridge is
>   running on port 51826. [2018-5-31 23:10:37] [eWeLink] eWeLink HTTPS
>   API reports that there are a total of [108] devices registered
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/index.js:98
>   body.forEach((device) => { ^
>
> TypeError: body.forEach is not a function at
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/index.js:98:22 at
>   Object.parseBody
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/node_modules/request-json/main.js:74:12)
>   at Request._callback
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/node_modules/request-json/main.js:148:26)
>   at Request.self.callback
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
>   at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) at Request.emit (events.js:214:7) at
>   Request.
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
>   at emitOne (events.js:116:13) at Request.emit (events.js:211:7) at
>   IncomingMessage.
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)

So the terminal tells me there is a error on line 98 from the index.js, that will be the next part of the script:

```
var devicesFromApi = new Map();
var newDevicesToAdd = new Map();

body.forEach((device) => {
    platform.apiKey = device.apikey;
    devicesFromApi.set(device.deviceid, device);
});

// Now we compare the cached devices against the web list
platform.log("Evaluating if devices need to be removed...");

function checkIfDeviceIsStillRegistered(value, deviceId, map) {

    var accessory = platform.accessories.get(deviceId);

    if (devicesFromApi.has(deviceId)) {
        platform.log('Device [%s] is regeistered with API. Nothing to do.', accessory.displayName);
    } else {
        platform.log('Device [%s], ID : [%s] was not present in the response from the API. It will be removed.', accessory.displayName, accessory.UUID);
        platform.removeAccessory(accessory);
    }
}
```

I found some similar problems with the fromEach function but I still can't seem to figure out what I should change in the script.

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` is not an Array, therefore you cannot invoke `.forEach` on it, you can try converting it like

`Array.from(body).forEach(function (device) { ... }`

Take a look on this answer that might help : [forEach is not a function error with JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969974/foreach-is-not-a-function-error-with-javascript-array)

Comment: So if I'm right, I should change the script on line 98 from: 
body.forEach((device) => {
    platform.apiKey = device.apikey;
    devicesFromApi.set(device.deviceid, device);
});

To:

Array.from(body).forEach(function (device) {
    platform.apiKey = device.apikey;
    devicesFromApi.set(device.deviceid, device);
});