# Discord bot TypeError: client.guilds.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js, chatbot

I am trying to make my discord bot to print all the servers that it's connected to but when I try to run my code I get this type error: 
`TypeError: client.guilds.forEach is not a function`

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Conectat ca si: " + client.user.tag)

    client.user.setActivity("my brother kiko jr", {type: "WATCHING"})

    client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(guild.name)

    })

})

client.login("xyz")
```

Comment: I believe this question is already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969974/foreach-is-not-a-function-error-with-javascript-array

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you on?

Comment: I looked at the answer you linked here but still couldn't solve it

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming you're getting the error because you're using discord.js v12

If that is the case, your solution would be:

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    console.log(guild.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

no worries the problem ur facing right now is because you may have the version 12 of discord so i'd recommend u to use the following code

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild)=>{
console.log(guild.name)
})
```

or try re-installing discord with

```
npm i discord.js
```

and ur pc will install the version and u can start using it