# forEach is not function

Tags: javascript, foreach

Can someone explain to me how I can use forEach without an error message?
I'm programming since 1 month so maybe it's a simple mistake.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

let galleryImages1 = document.querySelector(".gallery-img");
let getLatestOpenedImg;
let windowWidth1 = window.innerWidth;



if (galleryImages1) {
    galleryImages1.forEach(function (image) {
        image.onclick = function () {

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: what is the error you r getting ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969974/foreach-is-not-a-function-error-with-javascript-array have a look at this.

Comment: well querySelector does not return a collection so there is nothing to loop over

Answer (score 1):

The selector `querySelector` returns only the first element. If you want to return all the elements which match your query use:

```
let galleryImages1 = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-img");
```

Comment: You cannot use foreach on a nodelist

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/votolentino/9orhcq4p/1/

Comment: It won't in every javascript engine, there are polyfils for latest browsers to use a for loop when foreach is called

Comment: Its not valid in typescript either

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-img")]` will generate an array and `foreach` can be used.

Comment: Its not backward compatible though, that's why typescript will force you to use a loop

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
document.querySelector(".gallery-img");
```

to

```
document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-img");
```

as `document.querySelector` return a single element and you can not use `forEach` on single element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let galleryImages1 = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-img");

if (galleryImages1) {
  galleryImages1.forEach(image => {
    image.onclick = () => {
      […]
    }
  });
}
```

Of course, I would use an `eventListener` to handle an `onclick` event, but I tried to follow your path.

Answer (score -1):

Two problems

1 -  The return type of document.querySelectorAll is NodeList and not Array which means it does not implement forEach method. Thus you need to use a for loop.
A nodelist is not an array and you cannot use forEach

Modern browsers use a polyfill to use a for loop under the hood
But its not doesn't work in all javascript Engines

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill

Typescript will throw an error too if you try and use foreach and will force you to use a for loop

2 - And use document.querySelectorAll and not document.querySelector to get a nodelist