# Change Paragram using DOM manupulations

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector("#myBtn").onclick = function () {
  console.log("Clicked");
  const h1 = document.querySelector("#myH1");
  const underline = document.createElement("u");
  underline.innerText = "Hey bro.";
  h1.innerText = "";
  h1.append(underline);

  const p = document.querySelector(".myP");
  p.forEach((element) => (element.innerText = "Thank You!!!!"));

  const btn = document.querySelector("button");
  btn.remove();
};
```

```
p.forEach((element) => (element.innerText = "Thank You!"));
```

I got: `Error TypeError p.forEach is not a function`

EDIT: Thanks For Answer this question I really appriciated

Comment: `querySelector` returns an HTML Element not an array like structure...

Comment: use `document.querySelectorAll(".myP")`.

Comment: Do you mean to use `querySelectorAll`? `querySelector` only returns the first matching node (if present), and not a node list.

Comment: Would you please provide HTML code as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [forEach is not function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393045/foreach-is-not-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector.

You could use the `getElementsByClassName` instead

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('myP"');
for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
  p[i].innerText = "Thank You!!!!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns just 1 element. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return a list of elements matching the given selector.

Answer (score 0):

First , Check you  createated a  query  or not.Then variable p is not defined inside the function.use query selector all for return all the elements in the query.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

querySelector returns an array that you can iterate with forEach. so you just need to change `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll`.

```
  const p = document.querySelectorAll('.myP')
  p.forEach((element) => (element.innerText = "Thank You!!!!"));
```