# What is wrong with my Javascript forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to loop through results that I have extracted from a database and write it to elements on a web page.

```
let customers = snapshot.numChildren();
console.log(customers);
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('customerNumber');
            
customers.forEach(customer => {
    elements.textContent = customer;
});
```

I am seeing the results for customers in the console but I am also getting this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: customers.forEach is not a function.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Note: elements is a nodelist - you can't `textContent` on a nodelist. You'd have to iterate over that too and apply `textContent` to each node.

Comment: This should help I suppose. it's very similar to your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969974/foreach-is-not-a-function-error-with-javascript-array

Comment: What is `snapshot.numChildren`? Does it have a `forEach` method? It would appear that it isn't an array.

Comment: Side note: `elements.textContent = customer` won't do anything. The `HTMLCollection` you get from `getElementsByClassName` doesn't have that property. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am querying Firebase Database. All the responses made me realise that I have constructed the forEach loop incorrectly. Once I have sorted this out I will put my solution here.