# How to get order total if quantity is updated

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects, onblur

Order entry form contains product name, price and quantity columns:

```
 <table id="order-products" class="mobileorder-table">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 80%;">
            <col style="width: 10%;">
            <col style="width: 10%;">
        </colgroup>

        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Product1
                    </td>
                    <td>
 <span class="mobileorder-price">0,98</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-product="4750211645618" class="quantity" id="product_Soodkogus" name="product.Soodkogus"
                       type="number" min="0" max="999999" value=""
                       onblur="orderSumRefresh()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    Order total <p id="js-doksumma"></p>
```

If quantity is changed, order total value should updated. I tried

```
<script>
    function parseFloatFormatted(txt) {
    if (typeof txt !== 'string' || txt === null || txt === "") {
      return 0
      }
    return parseFloat(txt.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', ''))
    }

function orderSumRefresh() {
    let totalAmount = 0
    const table = document.getElementById("order-products")
    table.rows.forEach((row) => {
        //for (let i in table.rows) {
        //   const row = table.rows[i]
       const hind = row.cells[1].querySelector(".mobileorder-price").value
       const kogus = row.cells[2].querySelector(".quantity").value
       const rowSum = Math.round(parseFloatFormatted(hind)* parseFloatFormatted(kogus)  * 100) / 100
       totalAmount += rowSum
       });
    var dok = document.getElementById("js-doksumma")
    dok.innerText = totalAmount.toFixed(2)
    }

</script>
```

but got error

How to properly implement this ?  Should pure CSS, javascript or query used?

Modern Chrome browser is used in mobile phone, ASP.NET 6 MVC Razor application.

Comment: You have to be aware that `for-in` on `table.rows` also includes the property `length`. There is no `table.rows[length]`. Just stick to `[...table.rows].forEach((row) => console.log(row))`

Comment: I updated question to use ` table.rows.forEach((row)` but this throws error `forEach` is not function

Comment: @Andrus table.rows.forEach gives always an error check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969974/foreach-is-not-a-function-error-with-javascript-array

Comment: I have updated my answer to use `for (const row of table.rows) {` that is similar to what are you trying to do like Nick Vu said.

Comment: @Andrus, `[...table.rows]` has `forEach` whereas `table.rows` does not. That is the reason for the spread. Alternatively you can use `querySelectorAll` and omit the spread, since it supports `forEach`.

Comment: `table.rows` itself is not an array object. You cannot use native methods (like `forEach`) of Array on `table.rows`, but we can loop through it with `for-of` (or normal `for` with index). Here is the document for `table.rows` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp. Or another choice is that you should convert it to an array object like `[...table.rows]` or `Array.from(table.rows)`, but it may hit performance slightly due to an array cloning operation. @Andrus

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#order-products tr').forEach()` avoids all those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick Vu said a first problem is in the for loop and I changed to:

```
for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
```

I find more problems in the code for example the index of the childNodes is wrong, using

```
console.log(row.cells[1].childNodes)
```

you can see there are 3 child and you are searching for the middle one (index: 1)

Then for accessing the data of the input element you need to use the `.value` property like this:

```
const kogus = row.cells[2].childNodes[1].value
```

********************* EDIT *******************

Changing the code as the answer has changed.

For accessing the data of the html element use `.innerHTML` property.

```js
function parseFloatFormatted(txt) {
    if (typeof txt !== 'string' || txt === null || txt === "") {
        return 0
    }
    return parseFloat(txt.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', ''))
}

function orderSumRefresh() {
    let totalAmount = 0
    const table = document.getElementById("order-products")
    /*
    for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        const row = table.rows[i]
        const hind = row.cells[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML
        const kogus = row.cells[2].childNodes[1].value
        const rowSum = Math.round(parseFloatFormatted(hind) * parseFloatFormatted(kogus) * 100) / 100
        totalAmount += rowSum
    }
    */
    for (const row of table.rows) {
        const hind = row.cells[1].querySelector(".mobileorder-price").innerHTML
        const kogus = row.cells[2].querySelector(".quantity").value
        const rowSum = Math.round(parseFloatFormatted(hind)* parseFloatFormatted(kogus)  * 100) / 100
        totalAmount += rowSum
    }
    const dok = document.getElementById("js-doksumma")
    dok.innerText = totalAmount.toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<table id="order-products" class="mobileorder-table">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 80%;">
        <col style="width: 10%;">
        <col style="width: 10%;">
    </colgroup>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Product1
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="mobileorder-price">0,98</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-product="4750211645618" class="quantity" id="product_Soodkogus" name="product.Soodkogus"
                    type="number" min="0" max="999999" value="" onblur="orderSumRefresh()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Order total <p id="js-doksumma"></p>
```

I suggest you to use the `console.log()` and log some variable to see if there is somethink wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is from here

```
for (let i in table.rows) {}
```

The value will be `"0"` and `"length"` (not index like your expectation), so it throws an error while trying to access `row.cells[0].childNodes` (`row.cells` is undefined)

I'd suggest you modify it to

```
for (const row of table.rows) {}
```

The full code can be

```js
function parseFloatFormatted(txt) {
  if (typeof txt !== 'string' || txt === null || txt === "") {
    return 0
  }
  return parseFloat(txt.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', ''))
}

function orderSumRefresh() {
  let totalAmount = 0
  const table = document.getElementById("order-products")
  for (const row of table.rows) {
    const hind = row.cells[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML
    const kogus = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].innerText
    const rowSum = Math.round(parseFloatFormatted(hind) * parseFloatFormatted(kogus) * 100) / 100
    totalAmount += rowSum
  }
  const dok = document.getElementById("js-doksumma")
  dok.innerText = totalAmount.toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<table id="order-products" class="mobileorder-table">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 80%;">
    <col style="width: 10%;">
    <col style="width: 10%;">
  </colgroup>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Product1
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="mobileorder-price">0,98</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-product="4750211645618" class="quantity" id="product_Soodkogus" name="product.Soodkogus" type="number" min="0" max="999999" value="" onblur="orderSumRefresh()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
Order total
<p id="js-doksumma"></p>
```

Comment: `row.cells[length]` never tries to get accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Nick is correct. Remember that table.rows is not an array but an HTMLCollection. You can fix the issue simply doing:

```
  const table = document.getElementById("order-products")
  for (const row of Array.from(table.rows)) {
  }
```

If you want to see for yourself that there is an "length" property being iterated over, open the dev tools, select the table from the elements tab, and run this snippet in the console:

```
for (let i in $0.rows) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log($0.rows[i].cells[0]);
}
```

You will see the last iteration print "length" and then throw an exception.

Comment: You do not need the  array while using `for-of`.