# document.children VS document.childNodes

Tags: html, dom, document, w3c

Interface [Document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-document-object) inherits interface [Node](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-nodetype) and specifies **Node.childNodes**. It works fine, but what is **children**? There's no such attribute in the specifications.

They work differently. If we have `<!doctype html>` node, document.childNodes contains it, but document.children doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

From [Matthew Flaschen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935720/1026):

> Element.children returns only element children, while Node.childNodes returns all node children. Note that elements are nodes, so both are available on elements.

`<!doctype html>` is a node is a DOM tree, so it is listed in `childNodes`, but it's [a DocumentType node, not an Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Node_type_constants), so it doesn't appear in `children`.

The reason you didn't find `children` in the spec you were looking at is probably because it's relatively new - it was added in [DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#parentnode) (which became a W3C Recommendation only in 2015).

If you need to traverse the `Element`s in the DOM tree (ignoring other node types -- such as text nodes), you will find `children` and related APIs (first/lastElementChild, previous/nextElementSibling) more convenient, but since they're newer, the old browsers don't universally support these APIs, so you should consult the [compatibility tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children#Browser_compatibility) and/or use a polyfill.