# Javascript: getting to child nodes from XMLDocument

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xml-parsing

Suppose I have the following XMLHttpRequest().responseText stored in `var response`:

```
{"success":true,"error":null,"body":"<modules>\n <total>5<\/total>\n <status>\n  <id>0<\/id>\n  <name>Archon<\/name>\n  <portCount>14<\/portCount>\n  <attached>true<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>1<\/id>\n  <name>PC4<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>2<\/id>\n  <name>APC<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>3<\/id>\n  <name>SL1<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>4<\/id>\n  <name>SW5-1<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>5<\/id>\n  <name>ALC<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>65<\/id>\n  <name>VirtualModule<\/name>\n  <portCount>16<\/portCount>\n  <attached>true<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n<\/modules>\n"}
```

After that, I did the following to extract the body:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var xml = json.body;
```

The object in `var xml` is a string, so I tried to attempted to parse it into an XMLDocument:

```
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
```

The trouble here is I have no idea how to get to the child nodes.  I have tried the following to get the value of total (which should be 5):

```
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("modules")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

But all I'm getting is a blank string.  I feel that this is something that should be very simple, but I'm simply not getting it.  I'm even more clueless once I want to get the value of the various name tags.

How do I go about getting the values of the child nodes?

Comment: You are not getting an empty string. `...nodeValue.toString()[0].charCodeAt(0) = 10` which is carriage return not empty.

Comment: @jrook Thank you!  This allows me to traverse through the nodes.  Is there a way to get the node values?  I understand that `var total = xmlDoc.children[0].children[0];` is the child node, but how do I get the value out of it?

Comment: By using nodeValue? `.children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ="5"`

Comment: the node **total** does not have any children. It has childNodes though.

Comment: @jrook Thank you very much!  I managed to get what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting my answer (and up-voting it!) if it helped you solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is not empty.

```
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("modules")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.charCodeAt(0));

10
```

which is the ASCII code for carriage return. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935689/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript) to find out more about `childNodes` and `children`. `xmlDoc.children` will give you an HTML collection which you can traverse and extract information from.

**Note**: I suggest editing the title of the question to be more helpful for those who may see it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As per requirement please try below code.

```js
var response = {"success":true,"error":null,"body":"<modules>\n <total>5<\/total>\n <status>\n  <id>0<\/id>\n  <name>Archon<\/name>\n  <portCount>14<\/portCount>\n  <attached>true<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>1<\/id>\n  <name>PC4<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>2<\/id>\n  <name>APC<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>3<\/id>\n  <name>SL1<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>4<\/id>\n  <name>SW5-1<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>5<\/id>\n  <name>ALC<\/name>\n  <portCount>0<\/portCount>\n  <attached>false<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n <status>\n  <id>65<\/id>\n  <name>VirtualModule<\/name>\n  <portCount>16<\/portCount>\n  <attached>true<\/attached>\n <\/status>\n<\/modules>\n"};

var xml = response.body;

var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');

var allChildNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;

var total = allChildNodes[1].textContent;

alert(total);
```