# How to get element who has more than one child?

Tags: javascript

In this code I get the number of children of all li  elements.
But how can I get li element who has more than one child?

```js
let liLength = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;

for (let i = 0; i < liLength; i++) {
  let liChildrenLength = document.querySelectorAll('li')[i].children.length;

  console.log(liChildrenLength);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a>list</a></li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-** Store all `li`s in array instead of length

**2-** Iterate through them and check the number of children

Something like this

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  if (lis[i].children.length > 1) {
    console.log(lis[i].children)
    console.log('------------------')
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a>list</a></li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) to an `Array` and use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).

Depending on if you want the number of actual elements vs nodes to be greater than 1, you should swap `childNodes` for [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).  `childNodes` will include **any** node, while `children` only contains `Elements`.  See this question for a little bit more detail: [What is the difference between children and childNodes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935719/691711)

```js
const arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).filter(li => li.childNodes.length > 1);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a>list</a></li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `.childNodes` will also contain text nodes (like a newline character). With this markup it will work, but if (for whatever reason) the anchor tags will be put on separate lines this won't yield the expected result ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4yjfsnuL/)).

Comment: @Andreas True, but I'm not sure if the OP wants only tags or also text nodes.  I'll add an addendum in the question regarding the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var liLength = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;

for (var i = 0; i < liLength; i++) {
  var liChildren = document.querySelectorAll('li')[i].children;
  if (liChildren.length > 1)
    for (var j = 0; j < liChildren.length; j++)
      console.log(liChildren[j]);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a>list</a></li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>list</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
        <li><a>list</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Same as parsing through an array use `[indexNumber]`

```
liChildren = document.querySelectorAll('li')[i].children;
liChildren[someIndex]
```

Hope that was the question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let li = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(function(li) {
   return li.children.length;
});
```