# What is the "text" child node of the html node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-node

I have tried to search but have not found an answer to this:

So I know that when a page is passed to or downloaded by a browser a tree structure representation of the page, called the DOM, is generated. Javascript can then be used to manipulate the nodes (objects representing elements) of this tree.

So now if I open Chrome's developer console and execute the command:

```
document.childNodes;
```

I get what I expect, namely two nodes which are the DOCTYPE and the html nodes

```
[<!DOCTYPE html>, html]
```

If I now assign a variable to the html and then check it's nodes like so:

```
var htmlNode = document.childNodes[1];
htmlNode.childNodes;
```

Something weird happens:

I get the "head" node as expected, and then there is a "text" node which I have no idea where it's coming from, then finally the "body" node as expected.

```
[head, text, body]
```

My question is where is this "text" node coming from?

[image]

Comment: Try putting end of head and start of body on same line, you’ll see.

Comment: Related, but not necessarily a duplicate: [What is the difference between children and childNodes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7935689/691711).

Comment: `<span>Hello World</span>` — the text node is the DOM object that holds the text "Hello World". The element node for the `<span>` is the parent of that text node.

Comment: What Akxe means is that whitespace alone can trigger the creation of a text node.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Akxe

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. I did not think about the white space.

Comment: I guess it only means there can be some text between `head` and `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although HTML says that the `html` element can only normally contain `head` and `body`, inter-element whitespace is of course allowed between any of these elements' start and end tags.

In the HTML DOM, inter-element whitespace is always distributed into text nodes. So, presumably, the text node you're seeing between the `head` and `body` element nodes is the inter-element whitespace between the `</head>` end tag and the `<body>` start tag.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I was seeing :)