# count child element and text with it jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to count the total element and text inside the p tag

```
<p class="parent">
  <span class="child">Span Text</span> 
  Text Text Text
</p>
```

it is possible?

```
$(p).children(').length
```

I'm using this code and this giving me 1 only but I want count 2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "count text"? Count the number of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for child nodes, and not children (read more about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935719/5157454)).

However, note that the actual number of child nodes in your HTML code would be 3, since there's a text node that holds the spaces before the span.

In this example, you can see the count of child nodes with or without the space before the span.

```js
const parent1ChildNodes = document.querySelector('.parent1').childNodes.length
const parent2ChildNodes = document.querySelector('.parent2').childNodes.length

console.log(parent1ChildNodes)
console.log(parent2ChildNodes)
```

```html
<p class="parent1">
  <span class="child">Span Text</span> 
  Text Text Text
</p>

<p class="parent2"><span class="child">Span Text</span> 
  Text Text Text
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I found my issue

Answer (score 0):

children method only returns valid objects. "Text Text Text" is not an html object. Therefore it doesn't count. If you place it in another span, the length of the children becomes 2.

```
<p class="parent">
  <span class="child">Span Text</span> 
  <span>Text Text Text</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but I can not add span bz its copy pasted content

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) instead of `children` to get text nodes counted. Note that `contents` will also count comment nodes.

```
$(p).contents().length
```