# How can I read child node names and their values in XML without specifying the tag name?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Here, I want to loop through the `<detail>` elements.  Although I can specify the `<detail>` tag name in my code, I can't use the tag names of the children.  I want to know the tag names of those elements and their values.

How can I loop through them and do this?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<body>
  <detail>
    <FirstName>t1 </FirstName>
    <LastName>t2</LastName>
    <Company>t3</Company>
    <Country>t4</Country>
    <Proviance>MP</Proviance>
    <city>indore</city>
  </detail>

  <detail>
    <FirstName>t5 </FirstName>
    <LastName>t6</LastName>
    <Company>t7</Company>
    <Country>t8</Country>
    <Proviance>t9</Proviance>
  </detail>

  <detail>
    <FirstName>t10 </FirstName>
    <LastName>t11</LastName>
    <Company>t12</Company>
    <Country>t13</Country>
    <Proviance>t14</Proviance>
  </detail>

</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about;

```
var details = xml.getElementsByTagName("detail");

for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
    if (details[i].childNodes) {
        for (var j = 0; j < details[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
            var detail = details[i].childNodes[j];
            if (detail.nodeType === 1)
                alert( "details node " + (i + 1) + ": " + detail.nodeName + "=" + detail.firstChild.nodeValue );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: xmlhttp.getElementsByTagName is not a function :-

Comment: xml in the example is a dom object not an xmlhttp object, so its `xmlhttp.responseXML`

Comment: Helo Alex, Could you tell me meaning of this line
in your code
if (detail.nodeType === 1)

Comment: It filters out nodes that are not element nodes (which is what you want to read) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132564/whats-the-difference-between-an-element-and-a-node-in-xml

Comment: Clear and simple ;3

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript) is a tutorial for parsing XML with JavaScript. Maybe it helps.

Hint: Search for tagName on the page

Answer (score 1):

Another great [article](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/11866/) of reading xml in javascript.

this tutorial only cover the IE support script, a little reading may help you make it compatible with other browsers.

you can search this text on google "XML Parser in Firefox Browsers" will give more results with example code.