# Why given code throws exception (Jsoup)

Tags: java, javascript, html, dom, jsoup

As it is said on so many forums that element is a special case of node in DOM.

But I got an exception that violate this rule.

It throws exception at statement, `elem.remove()`.

Here, ele is an element. `remove()` is a function in Jsoup API, that removes nodes and their descendants from DOM.

**Exception :-**

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object must not be null
    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:16)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Node.remove(Node.java:266)
    at XXX.YYY.ZZZ.Template_Matching.Template_Matching.removeProductLister(Template_Matching.java:80)
    at XXX.YYY.ZZZ.Template_Matching.Template_Matching.main(Template_Matching.java:376)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

**Code** :-

```
public static void function(Document doc1, Document doc2, String tag) {

        //Checking for ULs
        Elements uls_1 = doc1.getElementsByTag(tag);
        Elements uls_2 = doc2.getElementsByTag(tag);

        for (Element elem1 : uls_1) {

            // Check if elem1 exists in DOM, If No, then continue

            for (Element elem2 : uls_2) {

                // Check if elem2 exists in DOM, If No, then continue

                // If id matches, remove them
                if ((!"".equals(elem1.id())) && (elem1.id().equals(elem2.id()))) {
                    elem1.remove();
                    elem2.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should make sure that doc1 and doc2 are different documents.

Comment: Yes both are different.

Comment: @Alohci Can I discuss on this. I will explain my code on chat?

Comment: Sorry, no. Your code looks to have problems, but since I don't know JSoup, I'm not sure which one(s) apply. I suggest you change the code so that you're not removing elements in the inner loop like that. Build a list of elements that you want to remove, then loop backwards once through the elements list for each dom to remove the elements.

Comment: @Alohci Ohk, I will do that. But when I remove elements from both lists, then I put break. It does the same, that you suggests.

Answer (score 3):

The error happens when one tries to remove an element whose parent has already been removed. This could point to a bug in Jsoup. Doesn't removing a parent also remove the children?

A workaround is to first check if parent exists:

```
if (element != null && element.parent() != null) { // fixes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notNull
    element.remove();
}
```

Comment: It might happen if you are iterating elements and delete the parent before its children so probably jsoup is behaving correctly but the error is modifying the elements in a loop

Answer (score 2):

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object must not be null

You need to check that you aren't accessing properties of null objects...

Comment: But this problem not arises regulary. Sometimes it arises, sometimes it runs fine.

Comment: Surely elem1 and elem2 must not be null for the .id() accessor to not throw in the if(...)?

Comment: @Adrian Yes I checked this at the place where I commented `// Check if elem1 exists in DOM, If No, then continue`, If that element is not in DOM then continue, otherwise proceed.

Comment: Is this something you can debug? Put a break point on `elem1.remove()`, and check the objects involved.... ( I'm no Java expert, and I cant discern what platform, environment you are running this code on)

Comment: @Adrian I am making my project on maven, coding in java. USing Jsoup library for making DOM.

Comment: I have code where I am checking whether an element is `null` first before calling `remove` but still get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object must not be null`. I suspect this could be occur when a child is removed and then in same code a parent gets removed. Since removing a parent also tries to remove a child (which does not exist in DOM at that time) it throws an error. If this the case then it's a bug in Jsoup since Jsoup should be checking for nullity for removing the child, This is just a guess as I am not able to get my head around this.

Comment: I don't think the error is caused by element being `null`. A `null` object would throw `NullPointerException` and not `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: After checking the jsoup source code (https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.java) I think the reverse could be happening i.e. a child is being removed when the parent has already been removed. So, the error is probably correct.